# Calling a function from a different class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to call a simple function in a separate class in Kotlin in **Android**:

```
public class TestOfAClass: AppCompatActivity()  {
      public fun ThisIsATest(thisTest: String) {
           print(thisTest)
    }
}
```

but in when I have:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            ThisIsATest("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

I get am `Unresolved reference: ThisIsaTest`

So how can I call a function from a different class?

Comment: Seems that `ThisIsATest` is a class method, which you didn't specify in your question.

Comment: "So how can I call a function from a different class?" -- your function is an instance function, and so you would need an instance of the other class first, then you call the function on that instance.

Comment: Are you really trying to call a method in another activity? Because that might be a much deeper understanding issue than just initializing an object on which you would call an instance method. Maybe you could elaborate on your thoughts - what you have and what you want to have.

Comment: You cannot directly invoke the method of a different activity. You need to use startActivityForResult, and more importantly you probably don't even need 2 Activities if that's what you need (unless you have an assignment at school that tells you to do this

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to call is an instance method, the easiest answer is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

….
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            TestOfAClass().ThisIsATest("Hello World")
        }
    ))
```

the better answer is to rename your method to camel case:

```
     public fun thisIsATest(thisTest: String) {
           print(thisTest)
    }
}
```

That way you know its a method and not a class.

---

But if you are trying to communicate between two Activities, *this is not how to do it*. There are a few other options, one is using `startActivityForResult`:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

[How to manage startActivityForResult on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: I think there is a much deeper question in the fact that the OP does not understand Android and wants to call a method of another activity.

Comment: For sure. Sometimes though getting it working is what makes you realise its a mistake. Added a hint at that, thanks for the prompt @Michal